# Changing the size and location of a UIImage within UIImageView (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

In Swift, Im struggling to programically resize an image ( and its location ) within a UIImageView as follows:

```
  var housePic = UIImage(named:"house")
  var houseImageView = UIImageView(image: housePic)
```

[image]

I want to be able create a 2nd imageView with a cropped / resized version of the above houseImageView using the same image. The result is to show a section of the image from a grid like this..

[image]

All my efforts of resizing gives the following wrong result. I think i need to somehow resize the image and change the imageView bounds ??
If required, I can post lots of example failed code.

[image]

Comment: like a zoomed in view/loupe tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a 2nd image with size 100,100 and add this image to the previous `UIImageView` you can do  this:

```
    let imageName = "house.png"
    let originalImage = UIImage(named:imageName)!
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: originalImage)

    // this is only to visualization purpose
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    // create a new image resizing it
    let destinationSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
    originalImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // add the new image to the UIImageView
    imageView.image = newImage
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
```

Comment: @Sebastian - Thanks for your help but both your answers are incorrect as all they do is change the size of the imageView. I need the imageView to remain but  the image within the imageView to resize.

Comment: @pete - I get it and rewrite my answer. Now I put a code the create a uiimage and the uiimageview, than create a new image resizing the previous image and then add it to the previous uiiimageview